# ng serve killed after compile successful

Tags: node.js, angular, compilation, kill, serve

I am running "ng serve" the same way I have in the past. Now, after my angular app if fully compiled, the ng serve line is killed.  When navigating in my browser to the port I specified, I see nothing.  What could be wrong here?

```
cci40:licenses/gui/lilac | dev % ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 56789 --disable-host-check -c dev --progress
WARNING: Running a server with --disable-host-check is a security risk. See https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a for more information.
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:56789, open your browser on http://localhost:56789/ **

Date: 2018-10-11T19:37:45.075Z
Hash: 9d4cf3152e913e734212
Time: 59020ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 255 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 227 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 213 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 7.06 MB [initial] [rendered]
wdm: Compiled successfully.
zsh: killed     ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 56789 --disable-host-check -c dev --progress
```

Here are the versions I am using:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.7
Node: 8.9.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.7
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.7
@angular/cli                      6.0.7
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.7
@schematics/angular               0.6.7
@schematics/update                0.6.7
rxjs                              6.2.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Comment: are you running this command `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 56789 --disable-host-check -c dev --progress`? Can you also try in some other terminal (bash) other than zsh

Comment: yes that is the command I am running

Comment: can you simply run `ng serve --port 56789`  or by changing port `ng serve --port 4444`

Comment: tried both of these above, still had the same kill response after compiling successfully.  Tried with fresh terminals too

Comment: too difficult to guess, what may be cause. Can you try building your code with `ng build` and navigate to `dist/output-folder` and start any http file server for example `lite-server`. If lite-server is not installed then installed it `npm install -g lite-server`

Comment: It is pretty difficult to guess, I think this may be a memory issue, looking into it more